# Displaying adverts on a linux machine

Tags: debian

I have a linux machine which is currently running debian 7.
I need a piece of software to play a series of video adverts from a folder without the user being able to stop or mess around with the video. Literally just needs to be start up and go.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Configure an X server with no input devices. Disable VT switching and ctrl-alt-del just in case.

Don't run a desktop on the X server, just run a video player like mplayer, fullscreen.

Comment: ...and use [`nodm`](http://packages.debian.org/nodm) to set up an unattended X session. Also note that there are specialized Linux-based distros aimed at implementing kiosks. Dunno if there's a Debian-based one, but I think it worth googling.